# Innodb with full text search

Tags: innodb

We have to convert MyISAM table as InnoDB on Percona 5.6.13 server. These MyISAM tables are using full-text Indexing. So, If I will convert these tables as InnoDB then does It impact then query performance?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you convert `MyISAM` table as `InnoDB` it reduce memory Usage for `MyISAM`, increase memory Usage for InnoDB. Also see

[Converting tables from MyISAM to InnoDB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/converting-tables-to-innodb.html)